# Firefox error: "Expected media feature name but found ‘hover’"

Tags: css, firefox, hover, media-queries, interaction-media-features

I want to differentiate styling based on whether the client browser supports hovering or not. I read that media features would do the job and so I used the following structure:

```
/* Supports hovering */
@media (hover: hover) { ... }

/* Does not support hovering */
@media (hover: none) { ... }
```

While this works fine on Chrome (see specs below), on Firefox I get the error `Expected media feature name but found ‘hover’`. I am surprised, especially because it was [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Targeting_media_features) where I read about using `hover` as a media feature.

Is there anything I need to do in addition to get this working on Firefox?

---

For example [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover) about `hover` as a media feature doesn't work for me on Firefox while it does on Chrome.

---

**Chrome:** Version 67.0.3396.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)
**Firefox:** 60.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: I think you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. `:hover` has been supported since Firefox 2, Chrome 4 and IE 6. If your visitors are using browsers that old, I'd be telling them to upgrade their browsers, rather than adding a plethora of custom support :P

Comment: @ObsidianAge The difference is about mobile / desktop devices. Mobile devices don't support hovering and so the styling should be modified on these devices.

Comment: FYI, this media feature now works in Firefox > 64, which was released in Dec 2018 (which is really really late imo as this has existed in most browsers since 2015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This media feature is only available for Firefox version >= 64:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover#Browser_compatibility